# What IP address does my packet header contain?

Tags: networking, ip, router, nat

Learning recently about networking, I've come across the IP header of a packet, which is said to contain the source and destination ip addresses.
It makes sense that on a local network These could be 192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.11.
They are communicating with one being source and one being destination and switched for the other machine.

My question is how does this change when you suddenly have 2 machines communicating over the internet?

Say my IP is 192.168.0.10 on my network. My default gateway has a connection to the internet for which it was given 1 public IP address say its 17.5.7.8.
Now my buddy has his own router and home network, his IP may even also be 192.168.0.10, but we'll say he is host 15 for clarity (192.168.0.15). He also has a public IP assigned, say 18.6.8.9.

Given my example addresses, what does each packet header look like in each step?

Sender 192.168.0.10
Destination ???

Answer (score 0):

On the conventional Internet where everyone has a valid public IP address, the source and destination IP address are always the IP of the original sender and the final destination. When you send outside your local subnet, the packet will get forwarded to the router on the network, but that's done at the MAC layer.  The IP headers stay the same.

So for example, if my source IP is 1.2.3.4 and my router's IP address is 1.2.3.1, and I need to send a UDP packet to 20.30.40.50.  The src and dest IP addresses will remain 1.2.3.4 and 20.30.40.50.  It's just that the routing table of the sending computer will send the packet to the MAC address of 1.2.3.1 (the router).  The router, listening in promiscuous mode, will forward all packets to the appropriate outbound network.

The exception to this rule are routers that function as NATs (Network Address Translators) where they are multiplexing a private network of devices that are in the private IP address range (e.g. 192.168.1.x).  As far as the computers on the network are concerned, they are talking to a normal router and know nothing about the NAT behavior.  The router, acting as a NAT, will actually change the source IP address for outbound packets.  And for inbound packets, it will change the destination IP address to a node on the private network.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this may be confusing is because in your local network, your packets are being *switched* to your router and then after that are *routed* on the internet.

Assuming the destination IP address for your traffic is `18.6.8.9`, your router's publicly-routable internet IP is `17.5.7.8`, your local network's IP space is `192.168.0.0/27`, your computer's address on that local network is `192.168.0.10` and your router's address on that local network is `192.168.0.11` the situation is as follows:

When an application on your computer tries to a send a packet to 18.6.8.9 the operating system will first try to find an entry in its routing table for that address. It won't find an entry and so it will use what is called a default route, which will be pointing at your router, `192.168.0.11`.

Your operating system will realize it has a "direct" connection to `192.168.0.11`, which means itself and the destination are on the same network (`192.168.0.0/27`). Your operating system will then perform an ARP lookup on `192.168.0.11`, getting your router's MAC address, and in the *ethernet* header of your packet set the destination *ethernet* address to be the MAC address of your router.

When the packet leaves your computer, the *IP* header will have the source address as being your computer, `192.168.0.10`, and destination address
as being `18.6.8.9`. In the *ethernet* header the source address will be your computer's MAC address and the destination address will be your router's MAC address.

Once that packet reaches the router, the router will substitute the "real" internet-routable public IP address it's been assigned for the source address (replacing `192.168.0.10`). So on the open internet traffic will have a source IP of `17.5.7.8` and a destination address of `18.6.8.9`.

Comment: i know it've been i while, but i like your response, however is ``18.6.8.9`` the public ip of the destination router or the private ip of the destination machine/computer .. ?